# Boolean simplification issue

Tags: boolean-logic

Boolean simplification of B'C'+A'B'+A'C+BC' it's supposed to be A'+C'.

Currently I'm stucked at:

C'(B'+B)+A'(B'+C) =
C'+A'(B'+C)

I just can use the basic theoremes, nothing of k-maps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "not a question about programming"

Answer (score 0):

After a long thinking I mannaged to resolve it; if it helps anyone:

B'C'+A'B'+A'C+B'C' = C'(B'+B) + A'C + A'B = C' + A' + A'B = C' + A'(1+B') = A'+ C'